# Select a portion of a comma delimited string in DB2/DB2400

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I need to select a value within a comma delimited string using only SQL. Is this possible?

```
Data
A      B       C    
1     Luigi     Apple,Banana,Pineapple,,Citrus
```

I need to select specifically the `2nd item in column C`, in this case banana. I need help. I cannot create new SQL functions, I can only use `SQL`. This is the `as400` so the `SQL` is somewhat old tech.

Update..
With help from @Sandeep we were able to come up with

```
SELECT xmlcast(xmlquery('$x/Names/Name[2]' passing xmlparse(document CONCAT(CONCAT('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Names><Name>',REPLACE(ODWDATA,',','</Name><Name>')),'</Name></Names>')) as "x") as varchar(1000)) FROM ACL00
```

I'm getting this error

```
Keyword PASSING not expected. Valid tokens: ) ,.
```

New update. Problem solved by using UDF of Oracle's INSTR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question now. It is impossible to do this with the [built in functions within AS400](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/db2/rbafzmstch2func.htm)

You have to create an UDF of Oracle's [INSTR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php)

Enter this within STRSQL it will create a new function called INSTRB

```
CREATE FUNCTION INSTRB (C1 VarChar(4000), C2 VarChar(4000), N integer, M integer)
 RETURNS Integer
 SPECIFIC INSTRBOracleBase
 LANGUAGE SQL
 CONTAINS SQL
 NO EXTERNAL ACTION
 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE Pos, R, C2L Integer;

SET C2L = LENGTH(C2);

IF N > 0 THEN
   SET (Pos, R) = (N, 0);
   WHILE R < M AND Pos > 0 DO
      SET Pos = LOCATE(C2,C1,Pos);
         IF Pos > 0 THEN
         SET (Pos, R) = (Pos + 1, R + 1);
      END IF;
   END WHILE;

   RETURN (Pos - 1)*(1-SIGN(M-R));
ELSE
   SET (Pos, R) = (LENGTH(C1)+N, 0);
   WHILE R < M AND Pos > 0 DO
      IF SUBSTR(C1,Pos,C2L) = C2 THEN
         SET R = R + 1;
      END IF;
      SET Pos = Pos - 1;
   END WHILE;

   RETURN (Pos + 1)*(1-SIGN(M-R));
END IF;

END
```

Then to select the nth delimited value within a comma delimited string... in this case the 14th

use this query utilizing the new function

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(C,INSTRB(C,',',1,13)+1,INSTRB(C,',',1,14)-INSTRB(C,',',1,13)-1) FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want 2nd item only than you can use substring function:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
    A INT,
    B VARCHAR(100),
    C VARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @NTH INT = 3

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1,'Luigi','Apple,Banana,Pineapple,,Citrus')

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(CAST('<Name>'+ REPLACE(C,',','</Name><Name>') +'</Name>' AS XML).query('/Name[sql:variable("@NTH")]') AS VARCHAR(1000)),'<Name>',''),'</Name>','') FROM @TABLE
```

Comment: What if I want the 3rd item?

Comment: @LuigiMackenzieC.Brito  is your selection is same for all rows or different per row? means if 3rd item then third for all rows,

Comment: Yes, I need that nth item on all rows. In this case, the 14th. Also the data doesn't have fixed spaces, so I really need it based on the commas

Comment: @LuigiMackenzieC.Brito try changed query. I have used variable Nth

Comment: @LuigiMackenzieC.Brito which sql server version you are using?

Comment: the AS400 SQL server. If I'm not mistaken I think it's a DB2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76700/discussion-between-sandeep-and-luigi-mackenzie-c-brito).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming db2 which I don't use, so the following syntax may not be bang on but the approach works.

In Oracle I'd use INSTR() and SUBSTR(), Google suggests LOCATE() and SUBSTR() for db2

Use LOCATE to get the position of the first comma, and use that value in SUBSTR to grab the end of YourColumn starting after the first comma

```
SUBSTR(YourColumn, LOCATE(YourColumn, ',') + 1)
```

You started with "Apple,Banana,Pineapple,,Citrus", you should now have "Banana,Pineapple,,Citrus", so we use LOCATE and SUBSTR again on the string returned above.

```
SUBSTR(SUBSTR(YourColumn, LOCATE(YourColumn, ',') + 1), 1, LOCATE(SUBSTR(YourColumn, LOCATE(YourColumn, ',') + 1), ',') - 1)
```

First SUBSTR is getting the right hand side of the string so we only need a start position parameter, second SUBSTR is grabbing the left side of the string so we need two, the start position and the length to return.

Comment: I used the 2nd item as an example. I need the 14th though

Comment: The Oracle INSTR command has an optional parameter which lets you specify which instance of a string you want the position returned for. Don't know whether db2 LOCATE or CHARINDEX suggested by Sandeep above have that option.

Comment: charindex is the MS SQL version of LCOATE. I'll research if as400 has an INSTR equivalent. Thanks @OTTA

Answer (score 1):

A much *prettier* solution **IMO** would be to encapsulate a Recursive Common Table Expression (recursive CTE aka RCTE) of the data from the column C to generate a result TABLE [i.e. a User Defined Table Function (a Table UDF aka UDTF)] then use a Scalar Subselect to choose which effective record\row number.

```
  select
    a
  , b
  , ( select S.token_vc
      from table( split_tokens(c) ) as S
      where S.token_nbr = 2
    ) as "2nd Item of column C"
  from The_Table /* in OP described with columns a,b,c but no DDL */
```

Yet prettier would be to make the result of that same RCTE a scalar value, so as to allow being invoked simply as a Scalar UDF with the effective row number [as another argument] defining specifically which element to select.

```
  select
    a
  , b
  , split_tokens(c, 2) as "2nd Item of column C"
  from The_Table /* in OP described with columns a,b,c but no DDL */
```

The latter could be more efficient, limiting the row-data produced by the RCTE, to only the desired *numbered* token and those preceding *numbered* tokens. I can not comment on the *efficiency* with regard to impacts on CPU and storage as contrasted with any of the other *answers* offered, but my own experience with the temporary-storage implementation and the overall quickness of the RCTE results has been positive especially when other row selection limits the number of derived-table results that must be produced for the overall query request.

The UDF [and\or UDTF and the RCTE that implements them] is left as an exercise for the reader; mostly, because I do not have a system on a release that has support for recursive table expressions.  If asked [e.g. in a comment to this *answer*], I could provide **untested** code source.

Comment: I'd have more chances with the business side if I were to create a UDF rather than temporary tables. They really hate new/temporary tables going on and off the system.

Comment: What I described above is a UDF; either as a _table function_ (UDTF) generating a purely-temporary derived-table that is scoped to the query, or a _scalar function_ (UDF) that similarly generates a purely-temporary derived-table that is essentially scoped to the UDF invocation. The tables are effectively invisible; i.e. nobody needs to ensure they are taken "off the system", because they disappear when the query is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the locate_in_string function to work very well in this case.

```
select substr(
              c, 
              locate_in_string(c, ',')+1, 
              locate_in_string(c, ',', locate_in_string(c, ',')+1) - locate_in_string(c, ',')-1
              ) as fruit2
  from ACL00 for read only with ur;
```